# Javascript, checkbox 'checked' state

Tags: checked

I use next code:

```
<input class='checkbox' type='checkbox' id='agr_check' name='agreement' value='agreement'></input>
```

and

```
var ag_check = document.getElementById('agr_check');
alert(ag_check.checked);
```

if checkbox is checked first, javascript returns 'true'. but if i uncheck checkbox and then check it again, this javascript returns 'false'.

can you tell me why? and how to fix this problem?